# Bootstrap 3 table scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to limit the rows displayed, so I need to add scroll to the table.
I have tryed using some codes but in most cases the scroll is outside the table or it's not alighned with the `<thead>`.
Here is the code:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">              
<div id="dsTable class="container">           
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" style="height: 300px;">
    <thead>
      <tr style="width: 100%; display: inline-table;">
        <th class="info">Players</th>
        <th class="info">Position</th>
        <th class="info">Rating</th>
        <th class="info">Salary</th>
        <th class="info">Remove</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; width: 100%; position: absolute;">
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
        <td>23112$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
        <td>356324$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
        <td>213123$</td>
      <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is confusing, you need to explain more what exactly you are trying to achieve, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hywz1f4w/ with your code and i don't see anything wrong with it and in light of your question even don't understand what you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: and you have missing double quote here `<div id="dsTable class="container">`

Comment: ops sorry, I updated the code check it now, and see where the scroll is.

Comment: now it make more sense http://jsfiddle.net/hywz1f4w/1/

Comment: @StillMoJo Try my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hywz1f4w/2/

Comment: is there any way that the scroll can go inside the tbody?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can actually have a scroll bar on the table itself. But if you make the div a fixed height and add `overflow-y: scroll` to it. Then make the table take up 100% width and height of the div. Anything overlapping will be hidden until you scroll down?

Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hywz1f4w/3/

Comment: Perfect, thats what I was looking for :)

Comment: Excellent. Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have scroll on the table.

```
<div class="col-md-6">              
<div id="dsTable" class="container">           
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr style="">
    <th class="info">Players</th>
    <th class="info">Position</th>
    <th class="info">Rating</th>
    <th class="info">Salary</th>
    <th class="info">Remove</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="">
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
    <td>23112$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
    <td>356324$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
    <td>213123$</td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Remove" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Customized CSS

```
table {
        width: 100%;
    }

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;

    /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
    height: 220px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
}


thead th {
    width: 19.5%;
    float: left;
}
tbody td {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hywz1f4w/4/)